# moved column mysql varchar to date

Tags: mysql, sql

I should move the values ​​of a column like varchar `(dd / mm / yyyy)` to a column next to date type `(yyyy-mm-dd)`.
Column varchar is named `DATA`, column date is named `DATA2`.

Comment: Note that there is a manual for this kind of thing

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`STR_TO_DATE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) to convert your strings to MySQL Date format

```
UPDATE table
SET DATA2 = STR_TO_DATE(DATA, '%d/%m/%Y')
```

Comment: @MojoAllmighty yes you're right, I edited the answer.